# Use Excel VBA on a Mac to navigate to a webpage and type in the search box

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm using a code on a Windows PC on Excel to launch a website and input the value of the highlighted cell in the search box of that cell. Works fine on my PC all good.

I'm trying to do the same on my MAC. Obviously the copy paste doesnt work so trying to figure out how to do it.
The closest I got was to launch Chrome and navigate to the page but I get Run-time error '424' Object required on the line

```
' Find the search box and clear its value
chromeWindow.Document.querySelector("#search-text-pl").Value = ""
```

Here is the full code

```
Sub OpenChromeAndNavigateToTennisExplorer()
  ' Open Chrome browser and navigate to Tennis Explorer
  ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://www.tennisexplorer.com/list-players/"

  ' Wait for the page to load (you may need to adjust the time based on your internet   
speed)
  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")

  ' Find the search box and clear its value
  chromeWindow.Document.querySelector("#search-text-pl").Value = ""
End Sub
```

Is it possible to achieve what I'm after?

Thanks
Dimitris

I am expecting the code to launch Chrome, navigate to the site and select the search box so that I can input a value into it. I'm doing it step by step so at the moment I am trying just to reach the point where the cursor is in the search box